# Import csv in magento 2 is not working and show error "invalidAttributeName"

Tags: magento2, import, importexport

Import csv in magento 2 : Duplicates found in column names

I want custom import data to custom table " profilers " but it not working and show this error. 
I followed http://www.blogtreat.com/how-to-import-csv-file-to-custom-module-table-in-magento-2/ 
Please help me

My model

```
    <?php
namespace ...\Profilers\Model\ImportExport;

use ...\Profilers\Model\ImportExport\CustomImport\RowValidatorInterface as ValidatorInterface;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\ErrorProcessing\ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface;

class Import extends \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity
{
    const ID = 'id';
    const NAME = 'name';
    const ID_PROFILER = 'id_profiler';
    const FILE_PREFIX = 'file_prefix';
    const DELIMITER = 'delimiter';
    const DATA_SOURCE = 'data_source';
    const ENABLE_DISABLE = 'enable_disable';
    const FORMAT = 'format';
    const HOSTNAME = 'hostname';
    const USERNAME = 'username';
    const PASSWORD = 'password';
    const TYPE = 'type';
    const PORT = 'port';
    const LOCALFOLDER = 'localfolder';
    const DONE = 'done';
    const FOLDERFTP = 'folderftp';
    const DONEFOLDERFTP = 'donefolderftp';
    const LOCALFOLDERFTP = 'localfolderftp';
    const CODE = 'code';
    const SCHEDULE = 'schedule';
    const MAPING = 'mapping ';
    const ENABLELOCAL = 'enablelocal';
    const ENABLEFTP = 'enableftp';
    const IMPORT_EXPORT = 'import_export';
    const OUTPUTFORMAT = 'outputformat';


    const TABLE_ENTITY = 'profilers';

    /**
     * Validation failure message template definitions
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_messageTemplates = [
        ValidatorInterface::ERROR_ID_IS_EMPTY => 'Empty',
    ];

    protected $_permanentAttributes = [self::ID];

    /**
     * If we should check column names
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $needColumnCheck = true;

    /**
     * Valid column names
     *
     * @array
     */
    protected $validColumnNames = [
        self::ID,
        self::NAME,
        self::ID_PROFILER,
        self::FILE_PREFIX,
        self::DELIMITER,
        self::DATA_SOURCE,
        self::ENABLE_DISABLE,
        self::FORMAT,
        self::HOSTNAME,
        self::USERNAME,
        self::PASSWORD,
        self::TYPE,
        self::PORT,
        self::LOCALFOLDER,
        self::DONE,
        self::FOLDERFTP,
        self::DONEFOLDERFTP,
        self::LOCALFOLDERFTP,
        self::CODE,
        self::SCHEDULE,
        self::MAPING,
        self::ENABLELOCAL,
        self::ENABLEFTP,
        self::IMPORT_EXPORT,
        self::OUTPUTFORMAT,
    ];

    /**
     * Need to log in import history
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $logInHistory = true;

    protected $_validators = [];

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime
     */
    protected $_connection;

    protected $_resource;

    /**
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
        \Magento\ImportExport\Helper\Data $importExportData,
        \Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Import\Data $importData,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        \Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Helper $resourceHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator
    ) {
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->_importExportData = $importExportData;
        $this->_resourceHelper = $resourceHelper;
        $this->_dataSourceModel = $importData;
        $this->_resource = $resource;
        $this->_connection = $resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
        $this->errorAggregator = $errorAggregator;
    }

    public function getValidColumnNames() {
        return $this->validColumnNames;
    }

    /**
     * Entity type code getter.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEntityTypeCode() {
        return 'profilers';
    }

    /**
     * Row validation.
     *
     * @param array $rowData
     * @param int $rowNum
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateRow(array $rowData, $rowNum) {
        $title = false;
        if (isset($this->_validatedRows[$rowNum])) {
            return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
        }

        $this->_validatedRows[$rowNum] = true;

        if (!isset($rowData[self::ID]) || empty($rowData[self::ID])) {
            $this->addRowError(ValidatorInterface::ERROR_MESSAGE_IS_EMPTY, $rowNum);
            return false;
        }
        return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
    }

    /**
     * Create advanced question data from raw data.
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     * @return bool Result of operation.
     */
    protected function _importData() {
        if (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_DELETE == $this->getBehavior()) {
            $this->deleteEntity();
        } elseif (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE == $this->getBehavior()) {
            $this->replaceEntity();
        } elseif (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND == $this->getBehavior()) {
            $this->saveEntity();
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Save question
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function saveEntity() {
        $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Replace question
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function replaceEntity() {
        $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Deletes question data from raw data.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function deleteEntity() {
        $ids = [];
        while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
            foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
                $this->validateRow($rowData, $rowNum);
                if (!$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum)) {
                    $rowId = $rowData[self::ID];
                    $ids[] = $rowId;
                }
                if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                    $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);
                }
            }
        }
        if ($ids) {
            $this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique($ids),self::TABLE_ENTITY);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Save and replace question
     *
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    protected function saveAndReplaceEntity() {
        $behavior = $this->getBehavior();
        $ids = [];
        while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
            $entityList = [];
            foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
                if (!$this->validateRow($rowData, $rowNum)) {
                    $this->addRowError(ValidatorInterface::ERROR_MESSAGE_IS_EMPTY, $rowNum);
                    continue;
                }
                if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                    $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);
                    continue;
                }
                $rowId= $rowData[self::ID];
                $ids[] = $rowId;
                $entityList[$rowId][] = [
                    self::ID => $rowData[self::ID],
                    self::NAME => $rowData[self::NAME],
                    self::ID_PROFILER => $rowData[self::ID_PROFILER],
                    self::FILE_PREFIX => $rowData[self::FILE_PREFIX],
                    self::DELIMITER => $rowData[self::DELIMITER],
                    self::DATA_SOURCE => $rowData[self::DATA_SOURCE],
                    self::ENABLE_DISABLE => $rowData[self::ENABLE_DISABLE],
                    self::FORMAT => $rowData[self::FORMAT],
                    self::HOSTNAME => $rowData[self::HOSTNAME],
                    self::USERNAME => $rowData[self::USERNAME],
                    self::PASSWORD => $rowData[self::PASSWORD],
                    self::TYPE => $rowData[self::TYPE],
                    self::PORT => $rowData[self::PORT],
                    self::LOCALFOLDER => $rowData[self::LOCALFOLDER],
                    self::DONE => $rowData[self::DONE],
                    self::FOLDERFTP => $rowData[self::FOLDERFTP],
                    self::DONEFOLDERFTP => $rowData[self::DONEFOLDERFTP],
                    self::LOCALFOLDERFTP => $rowData[self::LOCALFOLDERFTP],
                    self::CODE => $rowData[self::CODE],
                    self::SCHEDULE => $rowData[self::SCHEDULE],
                    self::MAPING => $rowData[self::MAPING],
                    self::ENABLELOCAL => $rowData[self::ENABLELOCAL],
                    self::ENABLEFTP => $rowData[self::ENABLEFTP],
                    self::IMPORT_EXPORT => $rowData[self::IMPORT_EXPORT],
                    self::OUTPUTFORMAT => $rowData[self::OUTPUTFORMAT],
                ];
            }
            if (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE == $behavior) {
                if ($ids) {
                    if ($this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique(  $ids), self::TABLE_ENTITY)) {
                        $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList, self::TABLE_ENTITY);
                    }
                }
            } elseif (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND == $behavior) {
                $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList, self::TABLE_ENTITY);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Save question
     *
     * @param array $priceData
     * @param string $table
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function saveEntityFinish(array $entityData, $table) {
        if ($entityData) {
            $tableName = $this->_connection->getTableName($table);
            $entityIn = [];
            foreach ($entityData as $id => $entityRows) {
                    foreach ($entityRows as $row) {
                        $entityIn[] = $row;
                    }
            }
            if ($entityIn) {
                $this->_connection->insertOnDuplicate($tableName, $entityIn,[
                self::ID,
                self::NAME,
                self::ID_PROFILER,
                self::FILE_PREFIX,
                self::DELIMITER,
                self::DATA_SOURCE,
                self::ENABLE_DISABLE,
                self::FORMAT,
                self::HOSTNAME,
                self::USERNAME,
                self::PASSWORD,
                self::TYPE,
                self::PORT,
                self::LOCALFOLDER,
                self::DONE,
                self::FOLDERFTP,
                self::DONEFOLDERFTP,
                self::LOCALFOLDERFTP,
                self::CODE,
                self::SCHEDULE,
                self::MAPING,
                self::ENABLELOCAL,
                self::ENABLEFTP,
                self::IMPORT_EXPORT,
                self::OUTPUTFORMAT
            ]);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    protected function deleteEntityFinish(array $ids, $table) {

        if ($table && $ids) {
            try {
                $this->countItemsDeleted += $this->_connection->delete(
                    $this->_connection->getTableName($table),
                    $this->_connection->quoteInto('id IN (?)', $ids)
                );
                return true;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

RowValidatorInterface.pjp

```
    <?php
namespace ...\Profilers\Model\ImportExport\CustomImport;

interface RowValidatorInterface extends \Magento\Framework\Validator\ValidatorInterface
{
    const ERROR_INVALID_TITLE = 'InvalidValueTITLE';
    const ERROR_ID_IS_EMPTY = 'Empty';

    /**
     * Initialize validator
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function init($context);
}
```

My etc

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/import.xsd">
    <entity name="profilers" label="Import Profilers" model="...\Profilers\Model\ImportExport\Import" behaviorModel="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Source\Import\Behavior\Basic" />
</config>
```

Error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I get the same issue and it's related to a magento2 bug where custome import without any sku column it's failed.

you can have a patch here :

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/22180/files

it's working on my side after all.

Answer (score 1):

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/etc**

**db_schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="custom_import">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="entity_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Entity Id" identity="true" />
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="name" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Product Name"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="duration" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Duration"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="CUSTOM_IMPORT_ID_PRIMARY">
            <column name="entity_id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

[image]

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/etc**

**import.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/import.xsd">
    <entity name="custom_import" label="Custom Import" model="VendoreName\CustomDataImport\Model\Import\CustomImport" behaviorModel="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Source\Import\Behavior\Basic" />
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/Files/Sample**

**custom_import.csv**

```
entity_id,name,duration
,"Name 1",90
2,"Name 3",120
```

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\SampleFileProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="samples" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_import" xsi:type="string">VendoreName_CustomDataImport</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/Model/Import**

**CustomImport.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\CustomDataImport\Model\Import;

use Exception;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data as JsonHelper;
use Magento\ImportExport\Helper\Data as ImportHelper;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\ErrorProcessing\ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Helper;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Import\Data;

/**
 * Class Courses
 */
class CustomImport extends AbstractEntity
{
    const ENTITY_CODE = 'custom_import';
    const TABLE = 'custom_import';
    const ENTITY_ID_COLUMN = 'entity_id';

    /**
     * If we should check column names
     */
    protected $needColumnCheck = true;

    /**
     * Need to log in import history
     */
    protected $logInHistory = true;

    /**
     * Permanent entity columns.
     */
    protected $_permanentAttributes = [
        'entity_id',
    ];

    /**
     * Valid column names
     */
    protected $validColumnNames = [
        'entity_id',
        'name',
        'duration',
    ];

    /**
     * @var AdapterInterface
     */
    protected $connection;

    /**
     * @var ResourceConnection
     */
    private $resource;

    /**
     * Courses constructor.
     *
     * @param JsonHelper $jsonHelper
     * @param ImportHelper $importExportData
     * @param Data $importData
     * @param ResourceConnection $resource
     * @param Helper $resourceHelper
     * @param ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator
     */
    public function __construct(
        JsonHelper $jsonHelper,
        ImportHelper $importExportData,
        Data $importData,
        ResourceConnection $resource,
        Helper $resourceHelper,
        ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator
    ) {
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->_importExportData = $importExportData;
        $this->_resourceHelper = $resourceHelper;
        $this->_dataSourceModel = $importData;
        $this->resource = $resource;
        $this->connection = $resource->getConnection(ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
        $this->errorAggregator = $errorAggregator;
        $this->initMessageTemplates();
    }

    /**
     * Entity type code getter.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEntityTypeCode()
    {
        return static::ENTITY_CODE;
    }

    /**
     * Get available columns
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getValidColumnNames(): array
    {
        return $this->validColumnNames;
    }

    /**
     * Row validation
     *
     * @param array $rowData
     * @param int $rowNum
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateRow(array $rowData, $rowNum): bool
    {
        $name = $rowData['name'] ?? '';
        $duration = (int) $rowData['duration'] ?? 0;

        if (!$name) {
            $this->addRowError('NameIsRequired', $rowNum);
        }

        if (!$duration) {
            $this->addRowError('DurationIsRequired', $rowNum);
        }

        if (isset($this->_validatedRows[$rowNum])) {
            return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
        }

        $this->_validatedRows[$rowNum] = true;

        return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
    }

    /**
     * Init Error Messages
     */
    private function initMessageTemplates()
    {
        $this->addMessageTemplate(
            'NameIsRequired',
            __('The name cannot be empty.')
        );
        $this->addMessageTemplate(
            'DurationIsRequired',
            __('Duration should be greater than 0.')
        );
    }

    /**
     * Import data
     *
     * @return bool
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected function _importData(): bool
    {
        switch ($this->getBehavior()) {
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_DELETE:
                $this->deleteEntity();
                break;
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE:
                $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
                break;
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND:
                $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Delete entities
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function deleteEntity(): bool
    {
        $rows = [];
        while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
            foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
                $this->validateRow($rowData, $rowNum);

                if (!$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum)) {
                    $rowId = $rowData[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN];
                    $rows[] = $rowId;
                }

                if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                    $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);
                }
            }
        }

        if ($rows) {
            return $this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique($rows));
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Save and replace entities
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function saveAndReplaceEntity()
    {
        $behavior = $this->getBehavior();
        $rows = [];
        while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
            $entityList = [];

            foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $row) {
                if (!$this->validateRow($row, $rowNum)) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                    $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);

                    continue;
                }

                $rowId = $row[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN];
                $rows[] = $rowId;
                $columnValues = [];

                foreach ($this->getAvailableColumns() as $columnKey) {
                    $columnValues[$columnKey] = $row[$columnKey];
                }

                $entityList[$rowId][] = $columnValues;
                $this->countItemsCreated += (int) !isset($row[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN]);
                $this->countItemsUpdated += (int) isset($row[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN]);
            }
            if (Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE === $behavior) {
                if ($rows && $this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique($rows))) {
                    $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList);
                }
            } elseif (Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND === $behavior) {
                $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Save entities
     *
     * @param array $entityData
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function saveEntityFinish(array $entityData): bool
    {
        if ($entityData) {
            $tableName = $this->connection->getTableName(static::TABLE);
            $rows = [];

            foreach ($entityData as $entityRows) {
                foreach ($entityRows as $row) {
                    $rows[] = $row;
                }
            }

            if ($rows) {
                $this->connection->insertOnDuplicate($tableName, $rows, $this->getAvailableColumns());

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete entities
     *
     * @param array $entityIds
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function deleteEntityFinish(array $entityIds): bool
    {
        if ($entityIds) {
            try {
                $this->countItemsDeleted += $this->connection->delete(
                    $this->connection->getTableName(static::TABLE),
                    $this->connection->quoteInto(static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN . ' IN (?)', $entityIds)
                );

                return true;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get available columns
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getAvailableColumns(): array
    {
        return $this->validColumnNames;
    }
}
```